# routing page in Odoo v8

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9

I received error 404 when try to route similar pages in Odoo8:

```
class vips_salepage(http.Controller):
@http.route('/salepage/<filialpage>', type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def page(self, filialpage, **kw):
    cr, uid, context, registry = request.cr, request.uid, request.context, request.registry

    # here my code

    return http.request.render('vips_shop.indexpage2', result)

@http.route('/salepage/', type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def page(self, **kw):
    cr, uid, context, registry = request.cr, request.uid, request.context, request.registry

    # here my code

    return http.request.render('vips_shop.filial_list_page', result)
```

Page /salepage/ displayed sucessfully.

When I try to get /salepage/filialname I receive 404-error.

If I remove

```
@http.route('/salepage/', type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def page(self, **kw):
    cr, uid, context, registry = request.cr, request.uid, request.context, request.registry

    # here my code

    return http.request.render('vips_shop.filial_list_page', result)
```

/salepage/filialname displayed ok!

In Odoo v9 all working fine in Odoo v8 i cannot using both routes at the same time.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been successfully resolved.
Error in the same method name under different routes